# Replacing characters between numerals with sed

Tags: macos, sed, rename

Given a `.txt` file with a list of files named:

```
2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_1.mov
2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_2.mov
2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_3.mov
```

How do I rename all the **`_`** in between the numerals to a **`.`** without changing the ones between the letters?

I want the output to be:

```
2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_1.mov
2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_2.mov
2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_3.mov
```

etc.

```
sed -E '/s/{0..9}_{0..9}/{0..9}.{0..9}/' /Users/medialab/Desktop/ls.txt
```

give me a error, `invalid command code .`

While I'm asking, how would this work with `rename` or `mv` if the target was files in a directory rather than a list of files in a `.txt` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** the following regular expression does the replacement:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{3})_([0-9])_([0-9])_([0-9])/\1.0\2.\3.\4.\5/' ls.txt
```

---

- Capturing a character between a range using Regular expression is made doing `[0-9]`, not `{0..9}`.
- When you do string replacement using regular expressions, you can use matching group defined by parenthesis. You can refer to these numbers using `\n`, where *n* is the number of the matching group (0 for the whole match).

  ```
  s/(foo)bar/\1-\0/ => foo-foobar
  ```
- Also sed command doesn't start with `/`.
- Finally, when you want a certain amount of characters in your regular expression your should use `*` (O to N), `+` (1 to N), or the number of characters you want `{MIN,MAX}`.

*NB:* The `-E` option is used for *extended regex*, which a more common kind of regular expression. You can also use equivalent `-r` option on Linux.

Comment: Thank you @Ulysse. I get `sed: illegal option -- r` without the `-r` I get `\1 not defined in the RE`

Comment: I'm not on OSX yet, I'll look on my mac. But you should try `man sed` and look at your options. `-r` stands for extended regexp, without it you'l have to escape your parenthesis and brackets.

Comment: ah. that is `-E` on OSX. Thanks! Works! I don't quite understand how the second half \1.0\2.\3.\4.\5` is working if you have a chance to explain. I gather the numbers are some sort of positional designator, except for the zero...

Comment: @Bleakley: Under the `-E` (or `-r`) option, the parentheses `(…)` in the regex mark matching groups.  In the replacement text, you can identify the matching groups with _`\n`_ where _`n`_ is the group number (count the left parentheses `(` to determine the group number; they can be nested, but aren't in this code).

Comment: @Bleakley: Note that `-E` works with GNU `sed` too, but as you've found out, the `-r` option does not work on macOS (or Mac OS X).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you. Does `(0-9)` always cause the numbers to be unchanged, i.e. 2015 will always be replaced with 2015? Or is there no actual replacement being performed?

Comment: @Bleakley: If you use just `(0-9)`, then (under the `-E` option), the regex looks for and remembers three characters, `0`, `-` and `9`.  If you want any single digit captured, then use `([0-9])`.  If you want 2-4 digits captured, say so: `([0-9]{2,4})`.   Etc.  If you don't use the `-E` option, the `()` and `{}` need to be escaped with a backslash: `\([0-9]\{2,4\}\)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Awesome. Very helpful!

Comment: Sorry, I was on a no computer week-end! I'll edit accordingly to @JonathanLeffler's answers

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what is `[0-9]{2}`? Is it two numbers or one number, so `up to 2`? I want exactly 2 numbers. My code is `echo $(ifconfig)|sed -E 's/inet ([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}).*/\1/'|grep inet` and I want to get ONE ip address like `111.111.111.11`
. But a lot of ips are the output.

Answer (score 0):

OSX doesn't have a built-in `rename` command like Linux. If you install one from an external source (like homebrew or macports or fink, etc) it would be helpful to qualify which one you're using, and what its options are. I'll answer without reference to `rename`, since it won't be as useful to the general macOS-using public.  (And to be honest, Linux doesn't have one single `rename` either -- I know of three different `rename` commands in different Linux distros, all with different options and usage.)

I might use awk for this rather than sed:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="__"} {f=$0; gsub(/_/,".",$1); printf "mv %s %s\n", f, $1 $2}' list.txt
mv 2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_1.mov 2015.273.2.1.1Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_1.mov
mv 2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_2.mov 2015.273.2.1.1Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_2.mov
mv 2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_3.mov 2015.273.2.1.1Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_3.mov
```

Broken out for easier reading, that is:

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="__"}` - set the field separator to the double underscore
- `{f=$0;` - store the original filename
- `gsub(/_/,".",$1);` - replace underscores with dots to the left of the `__`
- `printf "mv %s %s\n", f, $1 $2}'` - print our command. Pipe this through `/bin/sh` if it looks right.

Note that if you want to be resilient with punctuation and special characters, this is not the way to go. The following depends on bash due to the `${var/re/text}` construct, which is not part of POSIX.

```
while read file; do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue     # skip files that don't exist
  lhs="${file%__*}"
  lhs="${lhs//_/.}"
  echo mv -v "$file" "${lhs}__${file#*__}"
done < list.txt
```

While this is longer, it's also way easier to read and maintain. And you can include logic like the bit about skipping files that don't exist, which is nice.

Comment: OSX has `rename` available via homebrew. I think it is in Perl. It works nice.

Comment: @Bleakley, point taken. I've added clarification to the first paragraph.

Comment: I think zsh on OSX also comes with rename

Comment: @UlysseBN, zsh on my El Capitan macbook doesn't include a `rename` builtin.

Answer (score 0):

For `GNU sed`:

```
$ sed -r ':loop;s/([0-9])_([0-9])/\1.\2/;tloop' input.txt
2015.273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_1.mov
2015.273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_2.mov
2015.273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_3.mov
# add a 0 before the month.
$ sed -r ':loop;s/([0-9])_([0-9])/\1.\2/;tloop;s/[0-9]+/0&/2' input.txt
2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_1.mov
2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_2.mov
2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_3.mov
```

**Edit**

if the target was files in a directory, just do this:

```
# origion files.
$ find . -name '*.mov'
./2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_1.mov
./2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_2.mov
./2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_3.mov
# if don NOT use the e modifier of s command, we can get the final command.
$ find . -name '*.mov' |sed -r 'h;:loop;s/([0-9])_([0-9])/\1.\2/;tloop;s/[0-9]+/0&/2;G;s/([^\n]+)\n(.+)/mv \2 \1/'
mv ./2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_1.mov ./2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_1.mov
mv ./2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_2.mov ./2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_2.mov
mv ./2015_273_2_1_1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_3.mov ./2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_3.mov
# use e modifier of s command to execute the substituted command.
$ find . -name '*.mov' |sed -r 'h;:loop;s/([0-9])_([0-9])/\1.\2/;tloop;s/[0-9]+/0&/2;G;s/([^\n]+)\n(.+)/mv \2 \1/e'
# changed files.
$ find . -name '*.mov'
./2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_1.mov
./2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_2.mov
./2015.0273.2.1.1__Your_Favorite_Home_Movie_3.mov
```

Explanation:

1. use `h` command to keep the origin filename in `hold space`.
2. use `:loop;s/([0-9])_([0-9])/\1.\2/;tloop;s/[0-9]+/0&/2` to rename all the `_` in between the `numerals` to a `.` and add a `0` before month.
3. use `G` command to append the `hold space` to `pattern space`, and then contents in `pattern space` are `CHANGED_FILENAME\nORIGIN_FILENAME`.
4. use `s/([^\n]+)\n(.+)/mv \2 \1/` to merge the command with `CHANGED_FILENAME` and `ORIGIN_FILENAME`;
5. finally use `e` modifier of `s` command to execute the command assembled above, which will do the actual works.

P.S:

1. `sed -r 's/([0-9])_([0-9])/\1.\2/g'` cannot deal with the **continuous** matching results, eg: `3_2_1`(`2_1` NOT substituted).
2. use `-E` for `BSD sed`.